# db design for dynamic data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql, database-design

I need to create a database for managing teams.  The 2 tables im wrestling with are the meet table and the events table.

Here is the basic flow

Team A can create a new track meet which will add 1 row to the meet table with meta data for the meet such as dates, location it also has to include a list of events.

Events is a table of about 500 possible events that can be competed at during a meet. Things such as distance, type of event, male / female, age

I want during the generation of a meet for the user to be able to select which events that meet will have.

So create a new meet, complete meta data, and select (for Ex) 30 events from a list of all possible events.

Soooo my question is what table structure best supports that.  I was thinking of a column in my meet table that holds and array of events.?  But is there a better way to handle that.?  Im using postgres and rails

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like a perfect use for the Rails [has_many :through association](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_many-through-association). You should have a `meet_events` join table. The `meet_events` table would have a foreign key (belongs_to) `meet_id` column in it which points to the meet it is associated with and an `event_id` column in it which points to one of the available events. Your `Meet` model would use `has_many :meet_events` and `has_many :events, :through => :meet_events`. That will allow you to get the event objects associated with this meet.

The `MeetEvent` model simply has two `belongs_to`. One for the `meet` and one for the `event`.

Here's a simple set of models:

```
class Meet < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :meet_events
  has_many :events, :through => :meet_events
end

class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :meet_events
  has_many :meets, :through => :meet_events
end

class MeetEvent < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :meet
  belongs_to :event
end
```

Here's an example of some data and what it is modeling:

### meets

```
id  |  name
------------------
1   |  Meet 1
2   |  Meet 2
```

### events

```
id  |  name
------------------
1   |  Event 1
2   |  Event 2
3   |  Event 3
```

### meet_events

```
id  |  meet_id  |  event_id
----------------------------
1   |  1        |  1
2   |  1        |  3
3   |  2        |  2
4   |  2        |  3
```

This is basically modeling that `Meet 1` has `Event 1` and `Event 3` in it. `Meet 2` has `Event 2` and `Event 3`. This also gives you the benefit of asking a particular `Event` what meets it is in. So for example, calling `event.meets` when `event` is Event 3, it will tell you that both `Meet 1` and `Meet 2` have that event in them.

Comment: so the meet event table would be simply  meet_Id, Event_ID  So if I meet had 15 events there would be 15 rows to make it work. ?  Im new to rails and doing this project as a learning project so any extra details would be nice.  It sounds like exactly what I want.

Comment: You would also have an `id` (primary key) column as well by default in Rails. If you had 15 events in your `events` table, then each `Meet` has the potential to add 15 rows to the `MeetEvent` table. Basically you would only add an entry to the `MeetEvent` table for each `Event` that needs to be associated with a `Meet`. I'll clarify this in my answer.

Comment: The `meet_events` table is often called a [join table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junction_table) if you want to read more about this relational database pattern.

Comment: This is great I am slightly familiar with the design and it seems perfect.  Thanks for the help

Comment: One final note is that the `meet_events` table can store additional data if you choose to. For example, you might store a field called `start_time` which would describe when a particular event is scheduled to start for that event.

Comment: I was just thinking I want to track results.  I was thinking of hanging 2 tables off of meet_events  something like to enter an athlete in a meet for an event HAve a meet_entry table (id | meet_event_id | user_id | entry time)  and meet results table (ID | meet_entry_ID | time | place)    or is it bad form to nest to that level

Comment: It's not necessarily bad form, but the more you nest, the more complicated, or numerous, your SQL queries will become, which will affect performance. In general, it's best to think of a table as representing an object in the real world. For your example, I'd probably have a meet_entry table that contained the results as well. A particular entry into an event is usually going to have results, so I think it makes sense to be in the same set of data.